# SyntaxError: Identifier 'client' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im tryna make a discord bot. whenever i try to run it with cmd i get this:

error in cmd:

```
C:\Users\kaalj\OneDrive\Desktop\Bot>node main.js
C:\Users\kaalj\OneDrive\Desktop\Bot\main.js:7
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
      ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'client' has already been declared
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

the code i got this far is:
Package.json

```
{
  "name": "gerda",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Gerda",
  "main": "= main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Jordy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.1.0"
  }
}
```

main.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Gerda is er');
});

client.login("Token");
```

*anyone knows what i have to do to make it run?*
(in my code i actually have my token filled in)

Comment: Please do not post images of the code until and unless it can't be expressed without them.

Comment: Please don't add code as images. People will be able to help you if you post a minimal, compact and reproducible code snippet.

Comment: You just need to remove the `client` declared at line number 3. So delete line 3 and you're good.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `client` declared at line number 3. You have already handled it in line 7 in detail. So delete line 3 and you're good.

Answer (score 1):

as you can see on lines: 3 and 7 , on both you declared const which is called: client.

it is that simple.